# unable to work with Hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, persistence

i am trying to work on somebody else code that is written using  spring+hibernate, ive to insert some data in database using hibernate, but i cant get access to the session through which i can insert data.

Have a look in my hibernate.xml file

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.my.app.dal.models</value>

        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

 <!-- <property name="mappingResources">
<list>
       <value>/hibernate/Stock.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
  </property>    -->
</bean>
```

and i am not sure why my code is not working.

below is my code

```
Configuration cf = new Configuration().configure("database/Hibernate.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    srb.applySettings(cf.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry sr = srb.build();
    SessionFactory sf = cf.buildSessionFactory(sr);
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    EmailEntity entity = new EmailEntity();
    entity.setToAddress(toEmail);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(tx);
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
    session.close();
    sf.close();
```

Comment: You are not using spring in your example.

Comment: i understand, i am new to hibernate and spring. I just want a quick solution, the java way so that i can insert something to db.

Comment: can you give us the context of what you wnat to do to see how we can use the same session factory configured in spring to do your persistence job

Comment: is your class a controller or a bean inside the spring context orwhat ???

Comment: One of the spring class has a method called sendEmail() what i am trying to do is insert the contents of email in database,

Comment: I have created my own method which i call after any call to sendEmail() and what i want from my custom method is to insert email data to db.

Comment: Ive seen many examples using above code but its not working in my case.

Comment: When you say "not working", what exactly do you mean? **Please add the error message**. I've had weird dependency conflicts in the past using Hibernate, so an error message would be really helpful to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I just got to know that my application is not using hibernate.cfg,xml instead it is using hibernate.xml and my model class includes annotation like  `@javax.persistence.Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "Id")
 private Long Id;
 
 @Column(name = "Subject", nullable = false)
 private  String Subject;

 @Column(name = "ToAddress", nullable = true)
 private  String ToAddress;

 @Column(name = "FromAddress")
 private  String FromAddress;

 @Column(name = "Message")
 private  String Message;

 @Column(name = "Status")
 private  boolean Status;`

Comment: I get the error which says org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration